# Is this the right way of using ProGuard in Android app?

Tags: android, export, proguard

I searched around the net a simple example of how to use ProGuard to protect your Android app from "code thieves". And I ended doing like this and you tell me if this is all it takes:
I opened **project.properties** file of my project in Eclipse, and uncomment and left this line: `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

Then I went to my project's **Android Tools => Export Signed Application Package...**
and export it with existing keystore which I made earlier when I was exporting app to test it in my phone.

In my project, above **project.properties** appeared to be created a new file **proguard-project.txt**, which I expected because the above line: `...proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`.

And that's it?
 Or no? Do I have to add something else because I've seen that others are adding some classes to inculde in file, ... Is that not included?

Help me to learn how to protect my app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeas, that's all if you want to protect your code only.

if you have resources that have copyrights, consider using the Android Copy protection.

When pubishing your app : go to section **Publishing options** subsection **Copy Protection**

Check  ***Copy Protection : On***

This prevent hackers to export the apk and by the way, prevent your resources from most of hackers.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, that is all you need to do.  If you use any external libraries, you may have to modify your config file in order to export your app.  You should test your protected app on your device to before publishing.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I feel so relieved now. I'm not using external libraries, it has only two classes and one xml, it's not demanding app. I tested it on emulator and it is working. I'll try it now on a real device. :) I only wanted to know is this the right way and that the proguard will protect my code.

Comment: It will be great help if you edit your answer to include how _"If you use any external libraries, you may have to modify your config file in order to export your app"_

Comment: @codingcrow did u find out how to use progaurd for this "If you use any external libraries, you may have to modify your config file in order to export your app"